# How to add com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PhoneNumber Param from Api explorer to a Form

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a form which takes Mobile number as com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PhoneNumber type param named as mobileNumber. It somewhat looks like this in API Explorer

[image]

This mobileNumber Field appears as a field enclosing number param which is the use to store number internally by PhoneNumber class. When I enter number here in the given format. It gives IllegalArgumentException (BadRequest 400).

Can anyone explain how to use PhoneNumber datatype in a form while using API Explorer for testing the API ?

Comment: It's possible that Endpoints doesn't know how to transform a string into a PhoneNumber object. You should have logs of the cause of the exception. You should post them, as they could be useful.

Comment: It was not logging anything much at Logging level Fine. But when I changed the Entity class to have the mobile number as String rather than PhoneNumber everything started working well. Though I am still using PhoneNumber class in the form to take input from the user then I convert it to String using getNumber() method of PhoneNumber class and use that String to save the mobile number in the Entity class.

I think there was some problem in saving Entity with mobile number as PhoneNumber type, in Datastore. I will recreate the same and will post the logs by increasing the logging level.